# Python: Converting Miles to Kilometers

Tags: python, range

I am an undergraduate statistics major attempting to learn some programming on the side. I purchased a python book and am stuck on a problem.

The chapter introduces For Loops and the preceding introduced functions.

Question - Write a program `disttable.py` that prints a table of mile to kilometer conversions for distances between 100 and 1500 miles at 100 mile intervals. Write a function to do the conversion. One mile approximately 1.609 km.

My code thus far -

```
def mile(x): 
        return 1.609 * x
def main():
    for n in range(100,100,1501):
        print(n,miles(n))
```

When I call `main()`, nothing happens. No error message.

I tried to place the for loop inside `main()`, however, I am unsure how to define the local variable inside the `main()` when I move the for loop there, so I end up getting a error message stating the local variable isn't defined.

Comment: Change `range(100,100,1501)` to `range(100,1501,100)`

Comment: You swapped the end and step.

Comment: Also, once you fix that, you're going to get a `NameError` because `miles` and `mile` aren't the same thing.

Comment: syntax is range(start, end +1, step)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! As I responded to Ryan below, I had a blank out moment right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're stepping by 1501 instead of 100:

```
def mile(x): 
        return 1.609 * x
def main():
    for n in range(100,1501,100):
        print(n,mile(n))
```

Comment: Ryan, Thank you very much for your help. I just had a "duh!" moment. The previous questions in this chapter I completed with the correct range syntax (start, stop, step), yet somehow forgot to do it on this one!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `range` incorrectly.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) says:

> `range(start, stop[, step])`

Going from 100 to 100 with a step of 1501 gives you no values, so your range is empty and the loop never runs.  You might have meant `range(100, 1501, 100)`.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are now the most pythonic way of doing this

```
def mile(x):
     return 1.6*x 
def main():
     print [(x, mile(x)) for x in range(100,1501,100)]
```

The upshot is they evaluate lazily which for big lists means less memory pressure.